# How to share data between components in azure logic apps

Tags: azure, workflow, azure-logic-apps

I need to send flag (ex: updated = false) to HTTP component and send that in the HTTP depend on the time of execution. is it possible to create an expression on recurring component and send it to HTTP?

[image]

Comment: we can add additional parameter to recurrence component as condition, see the image [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkHYf.png
could you please more elaborate the ask .

Comment: thanks @AjayKumarGhose-MT for the reply but i need to send boolean value to HTTP depending on recurrence time. (it's scheduled for every 2 hour. i need to send one additional value to identify 4PM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need to send boolean value to HTTP depending on recurrence time.

We can only set the requirement time/date/day/week in recurrence, as @[Nadine Raiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16887744/nadine-raiss) stated.

According to your needs, you wish to transmit the boolean value to http. You must first **initialize the variable** and then create a controller called **condition**. From here, you may add the value for true/false and it will hit the logic app every 2 hours.

Here is my logic app designer :

[image]

Comment: ok got it, thanks. BTW is there any way to trigger information to assign variable? like Hour of execution?

Comment: Hello @Ishaka , Glad to be of help!! Could you please refer this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "Recurrence" action adequatly. You can define the exact days, hours, and minutes when you want your workflow to run.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence#add-the-recurrence-trigger

Comment: is there any way to get recurring hours in the HTTP component?